# Shading edges Node-setup not working

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, bevel

so I am trying to shade the edges of an object, by taking the dot product of Geometry-->normal and the bevel node. I am on cycles (CPU) on Blender 3.3. I already played around with the bevel radius and the color ramp. [image: Node setup]

But I don't see any effect on the default Cube (or my model...)[image: effect]

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: You speak of Cycles render engine, but posted a screenshot of material preview, that is rendered in Eevee. Use render preview (with Cycles chosen for rendering engine in render settings) or just press F12 to render.

Comment: Hi, I didn't know the material preview uses Eevee. But that is just on that screenshot. The result is the same when rendered or previewed. So that's not the issue.